# Preparing comma and line separated textarea for db / multidimensional array in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to transform something like this:

```
firstnameA,lastnameA,emailA
firstnameB,lastnameB,emailB
```

into a js/jquery variable that I can then post to my php script to insert row by row in a table.

So far I have managed to do this: it splits the input by new line and then by comma, creates a table to make it easy for the user to check their input and **in parralel builds an array that I will post to my script for further treatment**. The second part is not working at all (building the table works). I have looked at plenty of posts here on how to create multi-dimensional arrays in js but they all require that I know the exact dimensions of the array. However it could be 1,2 or 50 lines.

Here's my code:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#new_coll').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   if($("#names").val() != "") {
    
    var table = '<table class="table mt-4"><thead><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Email address</th></thead><tbody>';
    var i = 0; 
    var j = 0; 
    var data;
     
    $.each($("#names").val().split(/\r?\n/), function(e, elements) {
     table = table+'<tr>';
     $.each(elements.split(","), function(e, element) {
    table = table+'<td>'+element+'</td>';
    data[i][j] = element;
    j++;
     });
     var j = 0;
     table = table+'</tr>';
     i++;
    });
    table = table+'</tbody></table>';
    
    var posting = $.post("Connections/colleagues_add.php", data);
    $('#results').empty().html(table);
    
   posting.done(function( data ) {
    $( "#results" ).append( data );
   });
   }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="new_coll">
<textarea class="form-control" id="names" placeholder="Event description*" rows="3" required>
firstnameA,lastnameA,emailA
firstnameB,lastnameB,emailB
</textarea>
<button type="submit" id="verify" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Verify</button>
</form>
<div class="col" id="results"></div>
```

If you comment out line 16 it works with the table, however creating the array isnt working. My file where it gets posted to is just a $_POST dump.

I'd appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn your data into a multi-dimensional array like below, stringify it with JSON.stringify and post it to your php file. In php use json_decode to turn it into an php-array and then go from there with your database stuff.

```js
// SPLIT YOUR DATA BY NEWLINE
const data = document.getElementById("data").value.split("\n");

// BUILD NEW ARRAY
let json = [];
for (let i in data) {
  // SPLIT EACH LINE INTO ARRAY 
  // AND PUSH IT TO NEW ARRAY
  json.push(data[i].split(","));
}

// STRINGIFY YOUR NEW ARRAY 
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

```html
<textarea id="data" cols="50">
firstnameA,lastnameA,emailA
firstnameB,lastnameB,emailB</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I kinda solved it, happy to get more input though!

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').hide();
    $('#new_coll').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   if($("#names").val() != "") {
    
    var table = '<table class="table mt-4"><thead><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Email address</th></thead><tbody>';
    var i = 0; 
    var data = new Array()
     
    $.each($("#names").val().split(/\r?\n/), function(e, elements) {
     table = table+'<tr>';
     data[i] = new Array();
     var j = 0;
     $.each(elements.split(","), function(e, element) {
    table = table+'<td>'+element+'</td>';
    data[i][j] = element;
    j++;
     });
     table = table+'</tr>';
     i++;
    });
    table = table+'</tbody></table>';
    $('#results').empty().html(table);
    console.log(data);
    $('#add').show();
    
    $('#add').click(function(e) {
   $('#add').empty().html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>');
   var posting = $.ajax({   url        : 'https://httpbin.org/post',
          type       : 'POST',                                              
          data       : {'data':JSON.stringify(data)},
          success    : function(){ }
           });
   posting.done(function( response ) {
    $( "#step2" ).append( response );
    $('#add').empty().html('Done');
   });
   
   
   posting.fail(function( response ) {
    $('#add').empty().html('Error');
   });
    });
   }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <form method="post" id="new_coll">
          <div class="form-row mb-2">
            <div class="col">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="names" placeholder="Event description*" rows="3" required>a1,a2,emaila
b1,b2,emailb</textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row mt-4">
            <div class="col">
              <button type="submit" id="verify" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Verify</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="form-row mb-2">
            <div class="col" id="results">
             
            </div>
            <div class="col mt-2" id="step2">
                <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

For some reason the PHP part isnt working here but that works too!
Happy for any improvements!